# Why do my geom_lines fail to break into the correct colours?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I have run into a little issue concerning the use of the `geom_line()` function.
My data consists of a frame-by-frame manual video assessment of certain behaviour by trained observers, this leads to several thousand data points per observer. This is basically a vector consisting of 0s and 1s per observer, in which the 1 represents wanted behaviour and the 0 unwanted behaviour.

Playing around, I came up with the following:

```
# a dataset from a manual videoanalysis with frame by frame behaviour assessment in binary. 0 = no, 1 = yes.
data1<-read.csv("ObserversBehaviour.csv", ",", header=T)

# my solution of giving each observer his own line, without having to transform the entire set
Obsy0 <- rep(0,4528)
Obsy1 <- rep(1,4528)
Obsy2 <- rep(2,4528)
Obsy3 <- rep(3,4528)
Obsy4 <- rep(4,4528)
Obsy5 <- rep(5,4528)
Obsy6 <- rep(6,4528)
Obsy7 <- rep(7,4528)
Obsy8 <- rep(8,4528)
Obsy9 <- rep(9,4528)
Obsy10 <- rep(10,4528)

ObsData <- data.frame(data1,Obsy0,Obsy1,Obsy2,Obsy3,Obsy4,Obsy5,Obsy6,Obsy7,Obsy8,Obsy9,Obsy10)

#vector giving each observer a number
Obsall <- c(0:10)

#The list of individual frames of video M01 (4528 in total)
Framerange <- ObsData[["Frames.M01"]]

ylabels <- c("Observer0","Observer1","Observer2","Observer3","Observer4","Observer5","Observer6","Observer7","Observer8","Observer9","Observer10")

#Ob<n>value is the 1 or 0 assessment
#had to use as.factor() because for some reason my 0s and 1s are seen as continuous
GraphObserve <-ggplot(ObsData,ylim=range(Obsall),xlim=max(Framerange),aes(x=Framerange))
geom_point(aes(x=Frames.M01, y = Obsy0, colour = as.factor(Ob0value), size=as.factor(Ob0value)), shape=15) +
geom_point(aes(x=Frames.M01, y = Obsy1, colour = as.factor(Ob1value), size=as.factor(Ob1value)), shape=15) +
geom_point(aes(x=Frames.M01, y = Obsy2, colour = as.factor(Ob2value), size=as.factor(Ob2value)), shape=15) +
geom_point(aes(x=Frames.M01, y = Obsy3, colour = as.factor(Ob3value), size=as.factor(Ob3value)), shape=15) +
geom_point(aes(x=Frames.M01, y = Obsy4, colour = as.factor(Ob4freeze.0.no.1.yes), size=as.factor(Ob4freeze.0.no.1.yes)), shape=15) +
geom_point(aes(x=Frames.M01, y = Obsy5, colour = as.factor(Ob5value), size=as.factor(Ob5value)), shape=15) +
geom_point(aes(x=Frames.M01, y = Obsy6, colour = as.factor(Ob6value), size=as.factor(Ob6value)), shape=15) +
geom_point(aes(x=Frames.M01, y = Obsy7, colour = as.factor(Ob7value), size=as.factor(Ob7value)), shape=15) +
geom_point(aes(x=Frames.M01, y = Obsy8, colour = as.factor(Ob8value), size=as.factor(Ob8value)), shape=15) +
geom_point(aes(x=Frames.M01, y = Obsy9, colour = as.factor(Ob9value), size=as.factor(Ob9value)), shape=15) +
geom_point(aes(x=Frames.M01, y = Obsy10, colour = as.factor(Ob10value), size=as.factor(Ob10value)), shape=15) +

scale_colour_manual(breaks = c(0, 1),
  labels = c("No","Yes"),
  values = c("green4","red"),
  name="Assessment")+
#needed to let the wanted behaviour stand out, so I changed pointsize
scale_size_manual(breaks = c(0, 1), values=c(1,2), guide="none")+
scale_y_discrete(limit=Obsall, labels=ylabels, expand=c(0,0))+
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),breaks = round(seq(min(0), max(Framerange), by = 200),5000))+
expand_limits(y=c(1,-.5))

update_labels(GraphObserve,list(x="Frames (M01)",y ="Observers"))
```

This led me to a fair graph consisting of nicely coloured dots for every datapoint, but since the points were overlapping and still quite small, this was not my way to go. Instead of using `geom_point()` I went with `geom_line()`. The graph does represent every colour break as I want it.

So next I changed every `geom_point()` line to `geom_line()`, while keeping the rest the same. (The `scale_size_manual()` became quite redundant)

```
geom_line(aes(x=Framerange, y=Obsy0, colour=as.factor(Ob0value)),size=14) +
geom_line(aes(x=Framerange, y=Obsy1, colour=as.factor(Ob1value)),size=14) +
geom_line(aes(x=Framerange, y=Obsy2, colour=as.factor(Ob2value)),size=14) +
geom_line(aes(x=Framerange, y=Obsy3, colour=as.factor(Ob3value)),size=14) +
geom_line(aes(x=Framerange, y=Obsy4, colour=as.factor(Ob4value)),size=14) +
geom_line(aes(x=Framerange, y=Obsy5, colour=as.factor(Ob5value)),size=14) +
geom_line(aes(x=Framerange, y=Obsy6, colour=as.factor(Ob6value)),size=14) +
geom_line(aes(x=Framerange, y=Obsy7, colour=as.factor(Ob7value)),size=14) +
geom_line(aes(x=Framerange, y=Obsy8, colour=as.factor(Ob8value)),size=14) +
geom_line(aes(x=Framerange, y=Obsy9, colour=as.factor(Ob9value)),size=14) +
geom_line(aes(x=Framerange, y=Obsy10, colour=as.factor(Ob10value)),size=14) +
```

I thought this would work out just fine, but it didn't.

Instead of switching colours for every 0 and 1 in the file, it seems as though the color switches at the first and last 1 occuring in the data set.

The graphs from the above scripts: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf6yz.png

I can not seem to find an error in my code, nor do I seem to find a solution on the web. Is there anyone here who can help me solve this?

## Update

For a clearer overview I placed links to the resulting graphs from my previous scrips underneath them.

After the suggestion of putting my data in a "long" format, I used the following script:

```
data1<-read.csv("ObserversBehaviour.csv", ",", header=T)

Frames<-data1[["Frames.M01"]]
Obs<-paste0("Observer",0:10)
Obsy <- sort(rep(0:10,4528),decreasing=F)
Obsvalue <- stack(data1[,c(Obs)])
ObsData2 <- expand.grid(Frames=data1[["Frames.M01"]],Obs=paste0("Observer",0:10))  
ObsData2$Observer = Obsy
ObsData2$Assessment = Obsvalue$values

ggplot(ObsData2, aes(Frames, Observer, colour=Assessment)) +
  geom_line(show_guide=T) +
  scale_y_discrete(limit=0:10, labels=Obs, expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),breaks = round(seq(min(0), max(Frames), by = 200),5000))+
  expand_limits(y=c(1,.5)) +
  #The manual colorcoding actually failed, since it keeps returning this error "Continuous value supplied to discrete scale".
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c(0,1),
                 labels = c("No","Yes"),
                 values = c("green4","red"),
                 name="Assessment")
```

Although the colours now actually changed based on the value of the behaviour assessment, new problems arose.

The values of Observer5-10 have all been replaced by the values of Observer10.

By changing several parameters, I found that by changing the line size, values returned to normal. However, values for Observer10 disappeared completely.

The graphs from the new scripts:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhj8a.png (second image is the first graph)

Combining these issues with the fact that I cannot change the colours manually (even though I tried using `as.factor()` and `as.discrete()` on my values) I don't know what I can try now.

I am probably missing something obvious here, as a beginner with R.

## Update

Output of `dput(head(ObsData2))`

```
## structure(list(Frames = 1:6, Obs = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Observer0", "Observer1", "Observer2", "Observer3", 
## "Observer4", "Observer5", "Observer6", "Observer7", "Observer8", 
## "Observer9", "Observer10"), class = "factor"), Observer = c(0L, 
## 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Assessment = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Frames", 
## "Obs", "Observer", "Assessment"), out.attrs = structure(list(
##     dim = structure(c(4528, 11), .Names = c("Frames", "Obs")), 
##     dimnames = structure(list(Frames = c("Frames=   1", "Frames=   2", 
##     "Frames=   3", "Frames=   4", "Frames=   5", "Frames=   6", 
##     "Frames=   7", "Frames=   8", "Frames=   9", "Frames=  10", 
##     "Frames=  11", "Frames=  12", "Frames=  13", "Frames=  14", 
##     "Frames=  15", "Frames=  16", "Frames=  17", "Frames=  18", 
##     "Frames=  19", "Frames=  20", "Frames=  21", "Frames=  22", 
##     "Frames=  23", "Frames=  24", "Frames=  25", "Frames=  26", 
##     "Frames=  27", "Frames=  28", "Frames=  29", "Frames=  30", 
##     "Frames=  31", "Frames=  32", "Frames=  33", "Frames=  34", 
##     "Frames=  35", "Frames=  36", "Frames=  37", "Frames=  38", 
##     "Frames=  39", "Frames=  40", "Frames=  41", "Frames=  42", 
##     "Frames=  43", "Frames=  44", "Frames=  45", "Frames=  46", 
##     "Frames=  47", "Frames=  48", "Frames=  49", "Frames=  50", 
##     "Frames=  51", "Frames=  52", "Frames=  53", "Frames=  54", 
##     "Frames=  55", "Frames=  56", "Frames=  57", "Frames=  58", 
##     "Frames=  59", "Frames=  60", "Frames=  61", "Frames=  62", 
##     "Frames=  63", "Frames=  64", "Frames=  65", "Frames=  66", 
##     "Frames=  67", "Frames=  68", "Frames=  69", "Frames=  70", 
##     "Frames=  71", "Frames=  72", "Frames=  73", "Frames=  74", 
# Long patch of "Frames= <75-4502>"  omitted due to space saving 
##     "Frames=4503", "Frames=4504", "Frames=4505", "Frames=4506", 
##     "Frames=4507", "Frames=4508", "Frames=4509", "Frames=4510", 
##     "Frames=4511", "Frames=4512", "Frames=4513", "Frames=4514", 
##     "Frames=4515", "Frames=4516", "Frames=4517", "Frames=4518", 
##     "Frames=4519", "Frames=4520", "Frames=4521", "Frames=4522", 
##     "Frames=4523", "Frames=4524", "Frames=4525", "Frames=4526", 
##     "Frames=4527", "Frames=4528"), Obs = c("Obs=Observer0", "Obs=Observer1", 
##     "Obs=Observer2", "Obs=Observer3", "Obs=Observer4", "Obs=Observer5", 
##     "Obs=Observer6", "Obs=Observer7", "Obs=Observer8", "Obs=Observer9", 
##     "Obs=Observer10")), .Names = c("Frames", "Obs"))), .Names = c("dim", 
## "dimnames")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of `ObsData2`. That will make it easier to help you. Paste into your question the output of `dput(head(ObsData2))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem circumvented

With the help of my colleague and the use of `geom_tile()` instead of `geom_line()` the graph is now exactly as I want it to.

```
require("ggplot2")

data1<-read.csv("ObserversBehaviour.csv", ",", header=T)

Frames<-data1[["Frames.M01"]]
Obs.lab<-paste0("Observer",0:10)
Obsy <- sort(rep(1:11,4528),decreasing=F)
Obsvalue <- stack(data1[,c(Obs.lab)])

ObsData2 <- expand.grid(Frames=data1[["Frames.M01"]],Obs.lab=paste0("Observer",0:10))  
ObsData2$Observer = Obsy
ObsData2$Assessment = Obsvalue$values

GraphObserve <- ggplot(ObsData2, aes(Frames, Observer, height=.9)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(Assessment)))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("0"="green4", "1"="red"), labels= c("No", "Yes"))+
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0), limit=1:11, labels=Obs.lab)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks = round(seq(min(0), max(Frames), by = 200),5000))
  update_labels(GraphObserve,list(x="Frames (M01)",y ="Observers"))
```

The colour breaks occur exactly where they need to, there is no overlap and all observers are listed in the plot.

Although this does not actually solves the problems occurring in my former script, it does provide a better result.

Final graph:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syq0t.png

Thank you eipi10, for showing me how to compact my script.

Answer (score 3):

This will be much easier if you put your data in "long" format. Here's an example with fake data:

```
## Create fake data in long format
ObsData = expand.grid(Frames=1:4258, Obs=paste0("Observer",0:10))

# Add y values
set.seed(10)
ObsData$y = cumsum(rnorm(4258*11))
```

In a long-form data frame, all the observers are "stacked" into a single factor variable (`Obs`) with 11 categories--one for each observer. Now you can use this as the grouping variable for a colour aesthetic in `ggplot`.

```
## Plot with a different color for each observer
ggplot(ObsData, aes(Frames, y, colour=Obs)) +
         geom_line()
```

Here's what the graph looks like with the default colors, but you can change that by adding `scale_colour_manual()` to your plot and setting whatever colors you prefer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the excellent suggestion. Converting the data into the "long" format really helped a lot, but did not yet solve the entire problem. See my updated question for more details.